# PHP: return current URL

Tags: php, url, url-parsing

With php, I want to return the current url of the page I am currently on.

for example, if this script is run on http://www.google.com, I want to echo out 'google' sans http://

OR

if this script is run on http://173.244.195.179, I want to echo out '173.244.195.179' sans http://

I've looked at `$_SERVER` but haven't been able to get it to work. Suggestions?

Comment: You want to echo out 'google' or 'www.google.com' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting current URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216172/getting-current-url)

Comment: @Pekka, I have read that post and none of those do this exactly

Comment: ah, okay. This is not trivial, because there can be different scenarios: Consider `google.co.uk` where the last two parts must be stripped vs. `google.com` where it's only the last part. How do you plan to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ar = explode('.', $domain);

echo $ar[0];
```

Maybe?

EDIT: (Supports subdomains)

```
function domain()
{
    $ends = array('net','com','info','org');

    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $ar = explode('.', $domain);

    $result = '';

    $i = 0;
    $found = false;
    for($i; $i<sizeof($ar); $i++)
    {
        $j = 0;
        for($j; $j<sizeof($ends); $j++)
        {
            if($ends[$j] == $ar[$i]) $found = true;
        }

        if($found) break;
        $result .= $ar[$i] . '.';
    }

    return substr($result, 0, strlen($result)-1);
}

echo domain();
```

I'm going to put my money on that there's a way simpler or inbuilt way of doing this.

Comment: looks promising though one problem, the url of my site is `173.244.195.179` so the explode breaks this

Comment: HTTP_HOST is the target host sent by the client. It can be manipulated freely by the user. It less reliable then SERVER_NAME since it's defined in the server configuration. [Check out this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

Comment: If this is the case then simply replace HTTP_HOST with SERVER_NAME - my bad.