# What $_SERVER variable provide full URL

Tags: php, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216172/getting-current-url)
>   [PHP and invoking url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360452/php-and-invoking-url)

Say somebody is looking for

http://subdomain.domainname.com/somedirectory/somefile.htm

What $_SERVER variable contain http://subdomain.domainname.com/somedirectory/somefile.htm

Comment: `var_dump( $_SERVER);` and find it or a combination of entries.

Answer (score 18):

```
// Get HTTP/HTTPS (the possible values for this vary from server to server)
$myUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']),array('off','no'))) ? 'https' : 'http';
// Get domain portion
$myUrl .= '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// Get path to script
$myUrl .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// Add path info, if any
if (!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) $myUrl .= $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
// Add query string, if any (some servers include a ?, some don't)
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) $myUrl .= '?'.ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?');

echo $myUrl;
```

...is my most resilient routine for this.

Comment: +1 Without testing, this looks like the most complete answer.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` includes the path info and query string if present, so this is doubling those up for me. Removing the `PATH_INFO` and `QUERY_STRING` lines fixes it (YMMV, server configs may be different).

Answer (score 6):

You might like to try:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
```

A combination of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You need to build it yourself;

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You can also use `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to detect if HTTP or HTTPS.

I recommend using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as this is exactly what the user is looking for, before any rewrites or anything else, and includes GET variables

Answer (score 1):

There is no full url contain in $_SERVER. But you can use this code:

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "/" . $_SERVER['QUERYSTRING'] . "/";
```