# Forcing user to login when clicking on link

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

i have this code which i am using to send an approval to a user email.
what i need is : when the user clicks on the link; he should first login and then he can proceed the approval process.
I tried the following code to check if the session is not registered,then to force the user to login (index.php):

```
global $user_ID;
$user_ID = $_SESSION['empName'];
if ($user_ID == '') { 
header('Location: index.php'); exit(); 
} 
echo "<INPUT type='hidden' name='Code' size = '6' value ='hr1.php' />";
if(isset($_POST['Code'])){$Code = $_POST['Code'];}
mysql_close($con);
```

now i need a method to redirect user to the previous page (link)

any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While redirecting to login page then store a session value called return_url

```
$_SESSION['return_url'] = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Then if login is successful then check if return_url exists / not. If exists then return back to `$_SESSION['return_url']`

```
header("Location: ".$_SESSION['return_url']);
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly :)
i did :
    $_SESSION['return_url'] = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $user_ID = $_SESSION['empName'];
    if ($user_ID == '') { 
    header('Location: index.php'); exit(); 
    } 
on the link page,and :
    if(isset($_SESSION['return_url'])) {
    header("Location: ".$_SESSION['return_url']);
    } else {
    header("location:Main_Login.php");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't send your current url as `parameter` when he clicks the link and it's not logged in?

I mean, that you must add a `JS`, for example, that when you click the link, add to your url a `parameter` like: `?lastUrl=/foo/foo.com`

Then, you save the url into a variable, check if the user is logged in or not and return the variable (last url).

JS suggestion:

**Without jQuery**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('checkLogin');
    element.setAttribute('src') = element.getAttribute('src') + '?' + 
        window.location.href;
}   // or you can add it into onclick method of your link,
    // but I think this is easier.
```

Comment: and what if it's not a fixed url?

Comment: @AhmedAli What is the question? If you use this into your web page where you have the link, it will take `href` value. That value will be your current url, the url where you are right now. It doesn't matter if it's `/foo.com` or `/foo2.com` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a make for the authorization and include this file on every page were needed.

auth.php

```
<?php
session_start(); //remove this if you do this somewhere else
if (empty($_SESSION['empName']) && !isset($_SESSION['empName'])) {  
header('Location: index.php'); exit(); 
}
```

page.php

```
<?php
include 'auth.php';
echo "<INPUT type='hidden' name='Code' size = '6' value ='hr1.php' />";
if(isset($_POST['Code'])){$Code = $_POST['Code'];}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You will need `session_start()` to use sessions. After this it should work, and if not can you explain what doesn't work?

Comment: i did,what didn't work out was the redirection back to the first page that user gets on the mail (link page)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current page to a session before redirecting the user to the login page: `$_SESSION['current_url'] = get_current_url()`. See `get_current_url()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216172/getting-current-url).

Once login, you can just redirect the user to the previous page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['current_url'])) {
  header("Location: ".$_SESSION['current_url']);
} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```